# Do you get xp for transferring Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you transfer a Pokemon to the professor, do you get any xp?

Comment: You only get one measly candy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not gain anything but the candy for transferring a Pokemon to the Professor, save for a free Inventory slot.

Answer (score 4):

You get 1 candy for that Pokemon family, 0 experience and 0 stardust per transfer.

Comment: In special events as Helloween you will get double candies. But still no experience.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if you all might be wrong here. I have noticed on more than one occasion that I gained 500xp after transferring a large number of Pokemon in one visit to the Pokémon storage device. I didn't count how many but I would say it was late 20s to early 30s, possibly more. I know this could be coincidence but I didn't do anything else in this time to gain xp so there's a good chance it was due to transferring large amounts one after another.

Actually, my bad. Think I might have evolved one at the same time. Sorry

Comment: You do not get exp from transferring Pokemon. Just one candy of that chain.

Comment: If you gain XP through any means including catching or evolving a Pokémon and then immediately enter a menu, it won't display the XP you gained until you return to the main game screen.